# Angular: Count items matching a condition

Tags: angularjs

I have this array of items

```
[
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    completed: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Ninja',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Hello',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Baby',
    completed: false
  },
]
```

I'd like to display the count where completed = true in my view. I also need this counter to update automatically when an element goes from completed=false to true.
Is there a way to do this in angular?

Answer (score 7):

You should look about filter and use it to filter dynamically your array;
In your controller declare your filter like this

```
$scope.completedFilter(object) {
    return object.completed === true;
}
```

After in your template you can just add

```
{{(myArray | filter:completedFilter).length}}
```

And your count will be automatically changed with the completed

Note: you can also declare a filter in you module that could be proper if you want to reuse it in another controller

Comment: Nice idea, but I bet the filter approach has the same performance implications as using $watch with large arrays of items.   It all depends on how the filter is implemented, and my guess is that it relies on angular.equals which is a potential performance killer.

Comment: or just add it straight in the view as...
{{(myArray | filter: { completed : true } ).length}}

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches you could take, but they all start by caching the count of the number of items that are completed when the controller loads.

You could use the [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) function to monitor the array, and update a counter when the object changes. The following is untested, but should give you a sense of how to do it

```
function myCtl($scope, itemFetcher) {
  $scope.items = itemFetcher.get(); //retrieves your array of items
  $scope.numComplete = countComplete();

  $scope.$watch("items", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.items = newValue;
    $scope.numComplete = countComplete();
  }, true); // NOTE: passing true into $watch is necessary to do a deep compare (i.e. comparing object properties), and I think it is required in this case, but it has a negative impact on performance & memory.

  function countComplete() {
    var cnt = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
      cnt += item.completed ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return cnt;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can update the completed count in functions that modify the items completed state. The following code is also untested.

```
function myCtl($scope, itemFetcher) {
  $scope.items = itemFetcher.get(); //retrieves your array of items
  $scope.numComplete = countComplete();

  $scope.markItem = function(index, newState) { // this function is referenced in your HTML template
    $scope.items[index].complete = newState;
    $scope.numComplete += (newState) ? 1 : -1;
  }

  function countComplete() {
    var cnt = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
      cnt += item.completed ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return cnt;
  }
}
```

Using `$watch` is more convenient and less error-prone, but may cause performance issues depending on the size of the `items` array.  The second approach is more efficient, but tougher to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Is adding a $watch necessary ?

Try this way

```
 $scope.itemCount = function () {
    var cnt = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
        cnt += item.completed ? 1 : 0;
        console.log(item);
    });
    return cnt;
}
```

Just to check the count is getting updated i added an item on button click to items array

```
$scope.insertItem = function () {
    $scope.items.push({ name: 'Phani', completed: true });

}
{{itemCount()}}

    <input type="button" ng-click="insertItem()" value="Insert" />
```

Try the above approach